# When a cheesecake recipe says "freeze" for 1 hour do they mean literally freeze in the freezer or do you put in the refrigerator?

Tags: freezing, cheesecake

When a no bake American cheesecake recipe says "freeze" for 1 hour do they mean literally freeze in the freezer or do you put it in the refrigerator to cool?

Comment: Welcome! If you could link to the recipe ([edit] your post), you may get better answers.

Comment: 1 hour hardly freezes anything, especially a cake with such high sugar content. It's more like a quick chill.

Answer (score 6):

Given the context, I would say that this means to place in the freezer for one hour.  Otherwise, if the author wanted you to place it in the refrigerator, the recipe would state "refrigerate."